# minkube start..gives error: "Exiting due to RSRC_INSUFFICIENT_CORES"..Is it possible to start minikube on this Mac with 2 CPU cores?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, osx-elcapitan, macports

I want to start minikube to learn Kubernetes but am having trouble because of error `RSRC_INSUFFICIENT_CORES`.
My mac has 2 CPU cores and minikube docs say that 2 cores are required.
Here a the machine specs from "About this Mac":

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2008)
- Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- Memory 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

This machine has VirtualBox Version 5.2.35 r135669 but its not running, and working docker and docker-machine, as shown here:

```
✗ docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.16.1, build 

✗ docker --version
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
```

I have successfully installed minikube v1.25.1 using an updated version of MacPorts, as shown here:

```
✗ which minikube    
/opt/local/bin/minikube

✗ minikube version

minikube version: v1.25.1
```

I cannot start minikube and get error: `Exiting due to RSRC_INSUFFICIENT_CORES`.  Here is the output that I see from 2 different `minikube start` attempts:

```
✗ minikube start --cpus=2

   minikube v1.25.1 on Darwin 10.11.6
✨   Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: virtualbox, ssh
- Ensure your docker daemon has access to enough CPU/memory resources.
- Docs https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#resources

⛔   Exiting due to RSRC_INSUFFICIENT_CORES: Requested cpu count 2 is greater than the available cpus of 1

✗ minikube start --cpus=1

   minikube v1.25.1 on Darwin 10.11.6
✨   Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: virtualbox, ssh

⛔   Exiting due to RSRC_INSUFFICIENT_CORES: Requested cpu count 1 is less than the minimum allowed of 2
```

Please excuse newbie-ness--this is my first ever SO question!

Is it impossible to start minikube on this Mac?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To enforce operation on a single core, you can use the following options

> --extra-config=kubeadm.ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU --force --cpus=1

Please note that docker and `minikube` were designed to run on at least two cores. If available, please consider enabling hyperthreading.

Comment: Thanks! ..the answer should change "--cpus 1" to "--cpus=1" to avoid an error.  This advice works and I will paste the terminal output below.  But first I add that important files to review:
```➜  dockers minikube --extra-config=kubeadm.ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU --force --cpus=1 start
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default```

Comment: important files to review, especially value of "CPU":
~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json 
..also very relevant: docker vs. virtualbox driver;..minikube comes with its own, newer version of docker..I have 17.05.0-ce but minikube reports Docker 20.10.12
Yes, minikube can and does run on a machine with only 2 cores on one processor.  The answer also works if we change from "--cpus=1" to "--cpus=2" but it seems like the "--force" is needed in both cases.

Answer (score 30):

I ran into these errors on an M1 Mac because my podman (4.0.2) did not have the VM configured with enough capacity.  [Abhinav Sonkar](https://itnext.io/goodbye-docker-desktop-hello-minikube-3649f2a1c469) figured out how to fix this.  This builds on his trail blazing.

First you may need to get rid of your existing [VM in podman](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine.1.html):

```
podman machine stop
podman machine rm
```

Then recreate it with adequate specs and tweak the connections to [work around](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/podman/) another issue:

```
podman machine init --cpus 6 --memory 12288 --disk-size 50
podman machine start
podman system connection default podman-machine-default-root
```

After that I was able to install minikube from `brew` and start it with:

```
minikube start --driver=podman --container-runtime=cri-o
```

With that the `minikube` subcommands work and `kubectl` seems fine talking to it.  I've also gotten `minikube start` to work with `--kubernetes-version=v1.23.5`, `v1.22.5`, `v1.22.8` and `v1.23.2`.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13855#issuecomment-1078442219 shows how this can be done a bit more securely, but it makes `minikube` harder to invoke.

Answer (score 7):

I had the error on macOS because I had configured Docker Desktop to use only one CPU. I put 2 and the error was gone.[image: Docker desktop for Mac settings]

Answer (score 0):

I had the error on my windows and can bypass the CPU check using:

```
minikube start --extra-config=kubeadm.ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU --force --cpus 1
```

On Linux use:

```
sudo minikube start --driver=podman  --extra-config=kubeadm.ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. And I could resolve it using suggestion in this page.

```
--extra-config=kubeadm.ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU --force --cpus=1
```

works however it is not ideal because minikube could use more cpus.

Antoher solution that was suggested here is to go to Docker->settings...->resources then change the number of CPUs available to Docker to a minimum of 2. Make sure you have enough Memory and Storage as well. then press the "Apply and Restart"

This is all good but it won't have an effect on the minikube that have already been created with little resources in you used the --force option from before.

In order to fix that issue use:

`minikube delete --all`

then:

`minikube start --driver=docker`

Now minikube will use the resources you made available to docker...